# Handle multiple item in single controller? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am relatively new to Angular JS. Currently I met a problem, lets say I have 1000 items in a list. In order to display the details about each item I will pass the items_id to generate html example(123.html). In this case, do I need 1000 controller to handle this kind of situation?

Controller

```
 app.controller('item0001',function($scope,$http,$sce){
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.details=[];
    $http.get("https://api.com/test/product/0001").then(function(response){  
       var getData = response.data;
       $scope.data.push(response.data);
       $scope.bindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(getData.details);
       for(var i = 0; i<getData.specification.length; i++){
           $scope.details.push(getData.details[i]);
       }
    });     
});

    app.controller('item0002',function($scope,$http,$sce){
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.details=[];
    $http.get("https://api.com/test/product/0002").then(function(response){  
       var getData = response.data;
       $scope.data.push(response.data);
       $scope.bindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(getData.details);
       for(var i = 0; i<getData.specification.length; i++){
           $scope.details.push(getData.details[i]);
       }
    });     
});
```

View

```
<p>
<a href="{{items.id}}.html" role="button">View More</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Definitely not, just a single view and controller and use either query string or path variable to handle that inside your controller.

Comment: @imprezzeb Thank you for such a quick response. But is it means that I still need create 1000 different ID html file but with only single controller?

Comment: No just define single view (HTML).

Comment: Yeah, you're forgetting the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) rule.  A single controller that will handle all objects will be sufficient.  Then you will probably leverage [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).  This _may_ be a situation in which a custom [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) is indicated.  But definitely don't create multiple identical controllers.

Comment: @anied Thank you. Yeah, what i doing right now is really non DRY. Any link that can actually give me a hints about how to achieve this?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but reading up on custom elements/directives would be useful.  Something that will be written in markup as `<customProduct pid="numberAsNgRepeatVarHere"></customProduct>`.  Then you'd put an ng-repeat on or around that for each product number in the array.  Finally, I _think_ it's an antipattern to make your actual call from the controller-- probably create a "getProduct" service that accepts a pid and makes the actual call, and passes back the result via a promise or something.

Comment: Yeah I agree with @anied, to use factory to define all your http calls and use that service/factory method in your controller instead.

Comment: @imprezzeb Thank you. I will go through those suggestions and have a try on it. Appreciate help from both of you. Thanks.

Comment: @anied Thank you. I will go through those suggestions and have a try on it. Appreciate help from both of you. Thanks.

Comment: @xxq -- No problem-- good luck!  And remember, if imprezzeb's answer (or any other answers) below effectively answered your question, please give credit by selecting it as your chosen answer.

Comment: @xxq, you are welcome, happy coding then.

Comment: Here are some suggestion for you, if you want to learn angularJS, you would better to learn the concept of MVC(model view controller), in your case, view should be a reusable html template to render your item, controller will call your api to grab a specified item as data model and put it into view model and bind it with your view. Here is the link for  you  to learn the detail, it will benefit you in long run. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: @YoungLearnsToCoding Thank you will look it as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single controller and HTML.

Bind the HTML with some ViewModel (a property on `$scope`)

From your controller place the call to fetch item details (I am assuming you have fetch these details on click of some button) using a service.

In success callback of your service update the view model. and angular using 2-way binding, will update the view with last item fetched.

Controller:

```
app.controller('ProductCtrl', function($scope, ProductService) {
  var getProduct = function(productId) {
    ProductService.getProduct(productId).then(function(response) {
      $scope.productDetails = response.data;
    })
  };
});
```

Service:

```
app.factory('ProductService', function($http) {
  return {
    getProduct(productID) {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "https://api.com/test/product/" + productID
      });
    };
  }
});
```

HTML View:

```
<body ng-controller="ProductCtrl">
  <div ng-init="getProduct(0001)">
    <p>Name {{productDetails.name}}</p>
    <p>ID {{productDetails.id}}</p>
    <p>Description {{productDetails.description}}</p>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="getProduct(productDetails.id + 1)">Get Next Product</button>
</body>
```

I hope this gives you a basic idea of how to implement your requirement. Please elaborate your question so that I can provide a more specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

Define a single view (html) and controller to handle this.. example below.

productDetails.html (view)

```
<div>
  <span>{{productName}}</span>
</div>
```

productDetails.js (controller)

```
app.controller('productDetailsCtrl',function($scope,$http,$sce){
    $scope.productName = "";        
    $http.get("https://api.com/test/product/0001").then(function(response){  
       var getData = response.data;
       $scope.productName = getData.productName;       
    });     
});
```